# How to use web socket data at other functions in JS

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a wss connection in nodejs.

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws-url.com');
ws.onopen = function() {
    ws.send(ws.send(JSON.stringify(
        [151,
            {
                type: 151,
                channel: 'ticker',
                event: 'USR',
                join: true
            }
        ]
    )))
}
ws.on('message', msg => {
    const result = JSON.parse(msg)
        console.log(result);
    }
})
```

I can see result of ws.on succesfully and modify data inside it's scope
but i cant reach that data outside of wss scope.
i tried :

```
let result = ws.on('message', msg => {
    const result = JSON.parse(msg)
        console.log(result);
    }
}) 
console.log(result)
```

But it came empty.
How can i use result  variable outside of ws scope ?

Comment: Just pass the code you need to run when there is a message as callback handler for `ws.on(...)`. The `on()` function does not return anything, so you can't capture it as `let result = ...`. Just have your handler function forward the data to whatever other function(s) need to use your result data.

Comment: sorry i couldnt get it, can you code what you say?

Comment: You already have the code in your post, so no need for me to write the same thing: `ws.on(...)` _does not return_ anything. You can't get data out of it by using `let result = ws.on(...)`. Instead, you have to pass in a forwarding function, which you've done, and then you can work with `result` in that function, and you can make that function call `whateverOtherFunction(result)` so that you can work with the result there, too, etc. etc. Don't try to get access to it "outside of ws scope", just write the code that you need to run as part of the result handling.